# Reference to Originating Conditional Value within a Javascript IF Statement

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I often find that I write IF statements which immediately reference the value of the conditional statement.  For example, let's say I need to check to see if a string matches a pattern:

```
if (mystring.match(/mypattern/) {
    var mymatch = mystring.match(/mypattern/)[1];
    ...
};
```

I suspect that what I'm looking for doesn't exist, but I've wondered whether you can reference the conditional statement's value within the if block, the way you can reference "arguments" within a function.  In many cases, of course, I can rewrite it like this:

```
var mymatch = mystring.match(/mypattern/)[1];
if (mymatch) { ... };
```

But that's often not possible if there's a series of methods called.  For example:

```
var mymatch = $('.myclass')[0].text().match(/mypattern/)[1];
```

... that would throw an exception if there were no item [0] on which to call .text().  Is there some convenient shorthand I'm missing out on?  Or a better way to organize things?  Just curious, really — I'll go on living if the answer is no.

Comment: There is no clear solution. You can use **try catch** block or you need to check your array length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where relevant you can use the fact that the assignment operator returns a value in JavaScript, so for instance you can write things like:

```
if (assignedTest = testedValue) {
   //value of assignedTest is now available 
   //and conditional will only be executed if true
```

This could be used if the RHS was compatible or properly set-up **but** it's also a huge readability concern since it's very easy to confuse the assignment `=` with comparison `==`/`===`.

If you were particularly motivated to pursue this you could extract this type of functionality into a function that would behave in a reliable way: such as assigning the result of a closure to a named variable, and you could further tune the behavior to do other things (such as optionally evaluating to a different value within the test).  Ultimately it would primarily be making a simple structure more complex though.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  I had never considered that assignment returns the assigned value.  I'll keep your readability warning in mind, but as my current project is a personal thing, I can get away with a bit of idiosyncrasy.